# How to Create a WHILE loop to schedule script runs if NO ACCESS to crontab?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I wrote a simple script that allows me to ssh to a remote host to pull data from it and present that data on my local machine into a log file (including date and time):
**ssh ip 'df -Ph | grep Dataload_xps' >> /home/userid/Dataload-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log**

This works great, but I need to automate this, and I don't have crontab! (permission reasons)

I attempted this while loop, which isn't great:
**while true;
do ssh ip 'df -Ph | grep Dataload_xps'; sleep 30; done & >> /home/userid/Dataload-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log**

I need help in:

1. creating a while loop that runs this command every hour.
2. if there is no return on the command i.e. no disk space - create an error log

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You could add a `sleep` command to the loop ex. `sleep 3600` or `sleep 60m`

Comment: And you can use `$?` to act on the exit code (aka `0`=succesfull or `>0`=error)